Fibonacci recursive dynamic structure
I am trying to do an assignment that we had on test from Algorithms and I am struggling to implement Fibonacci for higher n (range of numbers).
I have to make a program that takes n from range n > 5O and the output is last n-th member of Fibonacci sequence. I have to use dynamic structure and recursion. Also I can use only standard libraries (so no matrix, containers, vectors etc.)
By dynamic structure i figuered they mean some sort of chained list so I managed to make this code
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class List
{
public:
    struct Node{
        int position;
        int value;
        Node *next;

        Node(int x, int y) : value(x), position(y), next(nullptr){};
    };

    Node *head;

    List() : head(nullptr) {}

    void printList(){
        Node *current = head;
        while (current){
            cout << "Pozice: " << current->position << ", Hodnota: " << current->value << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    void addNode(int value, int position){
        Node *newNode = new Node(value, position);

        if (head == nullptr){
            head = newNode;
        }
        else{
            Node *current = head;
            while (current->next != nullptr){
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = newNode;
        }
    }

    void deleteList() {
        while (head != nullptr) {
            Node* temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    void saveFile(){
        ofstream myFile("output.txt");

        Node *current = head;
        
        while (current->next != nullptr){
            current = current->next;
        }

        myFile << "Pozice: " << current->position << ", Hodnota: " << current->value << endl;

        myFile.close();
        cout << "Výsledky byly v pořádku uloženy!" << endl;
    }
};
int fibonacci(int n){
    List *list = new List();
    if (n <= 1){
        return n;
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

List *createList(int n){
    List *list = new List();

    if (n <= 0){
        return list;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        list->addNode(fibonacci(i), i);
    }

    return list;
}

int main(){
    int n = 33;
    List *fibonacci = createList(n);

    fibonacci->printList();

    fibonacci->saveFile();
    fibonacci->deleteList();
    return 0;
}

This only works for n < 34. But I need to make this work for n > 50. I am trying to figure out some optimization and I figured that the only way is to save values and call them in the calculation but I am struggling to see if it still would be recursion.
Could somebody please guide me in right direction what could I change to make it run for count n > 50. Also I´m not sure if I am meant to use Class because I have tried to implement it on code that we were doing in the seminar.
I don't expect someone to complete this assignment just trying to figure out what to improve so I can learn and pass my exam

"Also I can use only standart libraries (so no matrix, containers vectors etc.)" - std::vector is a part of standard library.

The trivial recursive Fibonacci algorithm becomes extremely slow at higher values. Consider using memoization since you already put previous numbers in the list, so you don't have to recalculate them. Also, use long instead of int to make sure that larger numbers fit.

You said you need to compute Fibonacci numbers, and your code shows some implementation of the list, which seems irrelevant. Do you know the definition of the Fib sequence? f[n] == f[n-1] + f[n-2] . Just calculate all the elements one by one, you can save them for performance. 50th element is not so big anyway (12586269025).

The intention of the assignment is to teach you about memoization, where your fibonacci function only calculates every fib(x) once and stores the result in the data structure. Also keep in mind that fib(47) is the last number that fits in a 32-bit unsigned int and likewise fib(93) for a uint64_t.

Yeah I know the Fib sequence but I am confused by the fact that we must use 'Dynamic structure' and 'Recursion'. I managed to do it with array and recursion but not both at same time.
Maybe i will try using memoization and see how far i can get.
Thanks for answers

Memoizing a recursive function is as simple as querying/assigning the result from a cache, eg int fib(int n) { store[n] ||= fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); return store[n]; }

@Martin Kudela wrote: I am confused by the fact that we must use 'Dynamic structure' and 'Recursion'. I am pretty sure that "dynamic structure" is what Wikipedia terms dynamic programming, which leads directly to the concept of memoization. In fact, the Wikipedia page for dynamic programming uses the Fibonacci sequence as an example.

"I have to make a program that takes n from range n > 5O and the output is last n-th member of Fibonacci sequence." <<< I don't understand that sentence. Could you please rephrase?

Note your current function fibonaccidoesn't use the variable list that it initialises.

If you want to do large Fibonnacci numbers by recursion and WITHOUT memoisation then you need a different recursion formula - one that looks at numbers around N/2 each time, not N-1 and N-2.
The following is based on the formulae for F2n and F2n+1 on the Wikipedia page for Fibonacci numbers. (Hence the separate treatment of odd and even arguments). The key thing is that the recursion involves N/2 at each step, so getting down to the base case(s) very fast and without repeated calculation of the same thing.
As already pointed out, Fib(93) is the best you can do within the confines of standard integer types.
(Obviously the following test could equally well be done by induction, but that's not the point.)
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned long long fib( unsigned long long N )
{
   static unsigned long long basecase[] = { 0, 1, 1 };
   if ( N <= 2 ) return basecase[N];

   auto N2 = N / 2;
   auto a = fib( N2 );
   if ( N % 2 )
   {
      auto b = fib( N2 + 1 );
      return a * a + b * b;
   }
   else
   {
      auto b = fib( N2 + 1 ), c = fib( N2 - 1 );
      return a * ( b + c );
   }
}


int main()
{
   for ( unsigned i = 0; i <= 93; i++ ) cout << i << '\t' << fib( i ) << '\n';
}

Output:
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   5
6   8
7   13
8   21
9   34
10  55
11  89
12  144
13  233
14  377
15  610
16  987
17  1597
18  2584
19  4181
20  6765
21  10946
22  17711
23  28657
24  46368
25  75025
26  121393
27  196418
28  317811
29  514229
30  832040
31  1346269
32  2178309
33  3524578
34  5702887
35  9227465
36  14930352
37  24157817
38  39088169
39  63245986
40  102334155
41  165580141
42  267914296
43  433494437
44  701408733
45  1134903170
46  1836311903
47  2971215073
48  4807526976
49  7778742049
50  12586269025
51  20365011074
52  32951280099
53  53316291173
54  86267571272
55  139583862445
56  225851433717
57  365435296162
58  591286729879
59  956722026041
60  1548008755920
61  2504730781961
62  4052739537881
63  6557470319842
64  10610209857723
65  17167680177565
66  27777890035288
67  44945570212853
68  72723460248141
69  117669030460994
70  190392490709135
71  308061521170129
72  498454011879264
73  806515533049393
74  1304969544928657
75  2111485077978050
76  3416454622906707
77  5527939700884757
78  8944394323791464
79  14472334024676221
80  23416728348467685
81  37889062373143906
82  61305790721611591
83  99194853094755497
84  160500643816367088
85  259695496911122585
86  420196140727489673
87  679891637638612258
88  1100087778366101931
89  1779979416004714189
90  2880067194370816120
91  4660046610375530309
92  7540113804746346429
93  12200160415121876738

